# Kallisto build keeps failing when attempting to link CXX executable

Tags: unix, build, conda, zlib

I'm super new to coding in general so apologies for any lack of clarity or conciseness. I'm attempting to make a build for Kallisto to use in RNA sequence alignment and I'm getting stuck at the "make" stage. The cmake was successful after a little fiddling and downloading a CXX compiler, but the make keep exiting with an error status:

```
[ 27%] Built target htslib
[ 93%] Built target kallisto_core
[ 96%] Linking CXX executable kallisto
/home/wahanson/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/kallisto.dir/build.make:88: src/kallisto] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:130: src/CMakeFiles/kallisto.dir/all] Error 2
```

the main error appears to be "cannot find -lz" causing the subsequent errors. From what I understand, this is referencing zlib1g-dev and/or an inability to find it within the path. I have installed zlib1g-dev through conda and made sure to update to no avail. If anyone could let me know what I'm missing or a next place to look it'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is getting a already pre-built kallisto package from bioconda an option for you? `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda kallisto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like the `zlib` package was not installed in the env. Fortunately, I've recently built kallisto and can share [the Conda environment](https://gist.github.com/mfansler/3e9f991c598c672e8e047d7114368dc2) I have been using, which I've tested on both **osx-64** and **linux-64** platforms:

**kallisto-build.yaml**

```
name: kallisto-build
channels:
  - bioconda
  - r
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - autoconf
  - automake
  - hdf5
  - cmake
  - cxx-compiler
  - zlib
```

Create and then activate this environment:

```
conda env create -f kallisto-build.yaml
conda activate kallisto-build
```

then follow [the kallisto instructions](https://github.com/pachterlab/kallisto/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installation) for building from source.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for sharing your environment! I'm still having a little trouble though as when I attempt to create the environment it says:
`EnvironmentFileNotFound: '/home/wahanson/kallisto-build.yaml' file not found`
Am I missing a step?

Comment: @WesleyHanson did you save the YAML file with the name `kallisto-build.yaml`?

Comment: Yes that was it! sorry for the silly mistake haha. Thanks so much for your help!!!